# Set credentials/password for remote connection in powershell on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I have 2 servers (both Windows Server 2012 R2). They both have an Administrator account with password xxx and the 2 servers are in the same network (domain). I didn't install/configure those servers.

I'm able to execute powershell commands from server 1:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
```

I can also use this command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -Credential Administrator -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
```

There pops up a windows and I have to fill in my password.
I want that only the option with Credential/password is allowed and only when this connection comes from server02.

How do I have to achieve this in powershell?

Comment: I think you're asking a different question than Colyn answered.  Specifically: You want to require the password be provided (not allowing the implicit use of the same user) and you also want to restrict any caller other than the single specific machine?  The latter would require a firewall change.  The former has various approaches, mostly involving a totally different user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a credential object with the `Get-Credential` cmdlet, store it in a variable, and use it with your `Invoke-Command`.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred
```